# FYI: Hentaigana coming soon

Tags: discussion

It is long overdue, but hentaigana (変体仮名) are finally coming with Unicode 10. This is a full set of 285 characters. See [here](https://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2016/11/hentaigana.html) for fuller details.

Comment: Aw, shucks. Hentaigana is boring and practical. I was really hoping for more emoji.

Comment: Of course, we then have to wait for the various operating systems to update their fonts to _support_ those characters, which might take a while...

Comment: @GoBusto The comment on the linked post said that HanaMinPlus already contains *hentaigana*. So it might be usable pretty much straight away with this font. (Broad support will of course take a while.)

Comment: @Earthliŋ I don't know anything about HanaMinPlus, but until characters are officially recognized by Unicode, they do not have defined codepoints. There is a range for undefined characters (PUA), but general communication is limited to those with special setups. One person's usage of the PUA may not correspond to another person's usage. So the same code point could be used for multiple, different characters--not necessarily even the same script. Such PUA-mapped fonts will need to be updated to the final Unicode code allocations for general usage.

Comment: @oals TR #51 was just released. It adds 113 new emoji. More details: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/  and http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-released.html  .